# How can $\sqrt{x} < 9 = [0,9)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

I have tried solving this but seem to be missing something.  I can't seem to figure out how to solve this problem. I get $x<81$ as my answer but I am obviously missing something. The answers are provided for our homework, I just can't seem to get there. Can someone show me HOW to solve this please?

Comment: The answer **should** be $0 \leq x < 81$.  Maybe you misread the answer key/question or its just wrong.

Comment: Well it must be wrong because that's what it says! I looked over it many times to be sure I was reading it right. Thanks!

Comment: @JeanieWebb If you could post the exact text of the problem, that would help us understand exactly what they're looking for and make sure there isn't an [XY misunderstanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.

Comment: Well, the sentence as written "$\sqrt x < 9 =[0,9)$" is unparseable and makes no sense.  $[0,9)$ is not a number and $9 = [0,9)$ is nonsense.  What is it *supposed* to mean?  If $\sqrt x < 9$ then $\sqrt x \in [0,9)$ (because $\sqrt x < 0$ is impossible).  And if $0\le \sqrt x < 9$ then $0 \le x < 9^2 = 81$ and $x \in [0,81)$. So.... I'm not sure how to interpret your question.

Comment: Oh god!  I *needed* to have terminology for the "XY misunderstanding"!  It's the bane of questions here. Thanks for introducing me to that term.

Comment: Instructions are:Determine the solution set of each. Use interval notation if possible. The problem is:  (sqrt \ {x} < 9 )

Comment: Sorry, new user. Still leaning this 'code.' $\sqrt{x} < 9$